# Get data from two tables with join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I m trying to select a list of brands from one table and brand descriptions from another. One brand can have more than one description. What I want to have is something like this:

```
Brand1
-brand1 description 1
-brand1 description 2
...etc
```

What I have now:

```
Brand1
-brand1 description1
-brand1 description2
Brand1
-brand1 description1
-brand1 description2
```

Model function:

```
function get_brand_desc() {
    $query = "SELECT a.id AS aid, a.brand, b.* FROM brands a
                LEFT JOIN brand_desc b ON a.id = b.brand_id";
    $q = $this->db->query($query);

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach($q->result() as $descs)
        {
            $data[] = $descs;
        }
        return $data;
    }else{
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Controller:

```
    $admin_data['descs'] = $this->admin_model->get_brand_desc();
```

View:

```
<?php
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach($descs as $desc) {
                echo '<li>';
                echo '<p>'.$desc->brand.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.$desc->description.'</p>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Since you have duplicate entries, maybe use SELECT DISTINCT ? If that wont cut it on its own, dont use b.* - instead write b.column_name etcetc

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that each brand has multiple descriptions. I would like to display the brand, and all its descriptions below it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order your query by brand, that will group all the `brand_desc` rows together. So, your query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    a.id AS aid,
    a.brand,
    b.* 
FROM 
    brands a
LEFT JOIN 
    brand_desc b ON 
        a.id = b.brand_id
ORDER BY 
    a.brand
```

Now, when you loop the items, you're going to have several rows repeating the brand name -- each brand description. Instead of thinking of this query as giving you a list of brands, think of it as giving you a list of all the brand descriptions. So when you output that, you'll have to define the grouping.

```
    echo '<ul>';
        $currentBrand = false;
        foreach($descs as $desc) {
            if ($currentBrand != $desc->brand) {
                if ($currentBrand !== false)
                    echo '</li>'; // if there was a brand LI open, close it
                echo '<li>'; // open a new LI for this new brand
                echo '<p>'.$desc->brand.'</p>';
                $currentBrand  = $desc->brand;
            }
            echo '<p>'.$desc->description.'</p>';
        }
    echo '</li>'; // closing out the brand that is left hanging open at the end
    echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: This answer seems more efficient just manipulating data with if else  rather involving aggregate function

Comment: +1. This is the right approach; as this answer indicates, the query needs to include an `ORDER BY a.brand`. It's really just a matter of suppressing the display of a "duplicate" `brand` on subsequent rows.

Comment: @Chris ... I didn't add this to the question ... but how would I add a `<form>` to input new descriptions to each brand? I added it after `echo '<p>'.$desc->description.'</p>';` but I get as many forms as descriptions. The form works ... that's not the problem ... just don't want it to show multiple times.

Comment: @ciprian You would output the form right before the `</li>`, sort of like this: http://codepad.viper-7.com/DvsVrh

Answer (score 0):

you never update your brand information in your foreach-loop. You should build an array of arrays:

$data['brand1'] => array of all descriptions of brand1
   $data['brand2'] => array of all descriptions of brand2
   [...]

Answer (score -1):

Build your query like this :

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT a.id AS aid, a.brand, b.descriptionColumn FROM brands a
            LEFT JOIN brand_desc b ON a.id = b.brand_id";
```

Comment: He would only get one row per brand, and not see all the related items in `brand_desc`

Comment: The issue seems to be that he's getting duplicate rows in his query, so he wants 1 row per brand, per desc, unless I missed something?